# Pattern for storing various types in a field

Tags: java, oop, enums, type-safety

In a Java class that belongs in a library, I have a field `size` that indicates size of image. It must be `int`, but some values are depending to devices, so other developers can set  various types for it:

1. thumbnail (value depends on device)
2. real size (value depends on device)
3. custom (arbitrary integer)

I want to restrict other developers (that use this library) to set value of `size` with one option from set of specific and meaningful options.My purpose is to show list of `legal options` to developer and also `type safety`, like `Enum`. But I think it is impossible to do that only by `enum`, so I create an interface and some classes:

```
public interface SizeMode {
}

public enum DevicePreDefinedImageSizeMode implements SizeMode {
    THUMBNAIL, REAL_SIZE
}

public enum CustomImageSizeMode implements SizeMode {
    CUSTOM_SIZE
}

public abstract class Size {

    private final SizeMode mode;

    public SizeMode getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public abstract int getDownSampleFactor();

    protected Size(SizeMode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }
}

public class DevicePreDefinedImageSize extends Size {

    public DevicePreDefinedImageSize(DevicePreDefinedImageSizeMode mode) {
        super(mode);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDownSampleFactor() {
        throw new UnknownError("????");
    }

}

public class CustomImageSize extends Size {
    private final int downSampleFactor;

    private CustomImageSize(CustomImageSizeMode mode, int downSampleFactor) {
        super(mode);
        this.downSampleFactor = downSampleFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDownSampleFactor() {
        return downSampleFactor;
    }

}
```

Now I can declare field `size` of type `Size` class and other developers are restricted to use one of sub classes of `Size` and initialize them with `THUMBNAIL`, `REAL_SIZE` or `CUSTOM_SIZE`.

But is there a better approach to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `Size` implementation that can only be created using set of static factory methods (or Builder pattern if you want):

```
public class Size {
    private final int sampleFactor;

    private Size(int sampleFactor) {
        this.sampleFactor = sampleFactor;
    }

    public static Size thumbnail() {
        return new Size(THUMBNAIL_FACTOR);
    }

    public static Size real() {
        return new Size(REAL_FACTOR);
    }

    public static Size custom(int factor) {
        return new Size(factor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited your answer and add it here:http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87518/70836 .

Answer (score 2):

In java Enums are classes and they can have members.

```
public interface ISize {
  public int getDownSampleSize();
}

enum Size implements ISize {

    THUMBNAIL(THUMBNAIL_SIZE); // Defined elsewhere.

    private int downSampleSize;

    Size(int downSampleSize) {this.downSampleSize = downSampleSize;}
    public int getDownSampleSize() {return downSampleSize;}
}

public class RealSize implements ISize {
  public int getDownSampleSize() {return /* do something complicated */;}
}

public class CustomSize implements ISize {
  private final int downSampleSize;

  public CustomSize(int downSampleSize) {
    this.downSampleSize = downSampleSize;
  }

  public int getDownSampleSize() {return downSampleSize;}
}
```

Then usage would be:

```
ISize s;
void resize() {
  int downSampleSize = s.getDownSampleSize();
  ...
}
```

This is similar to what you did but a little cleaner. It saves you from having both `Size` and `SizeMode`.

Comment: @ It seems that code has some errors.Also it has another problem:CUSTOM_SIZE will be only 0,not arbitrary integer.